# Ant CompileTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader

Tags: jenkins, build, ant

Could anyone help this issue?

/jenkins/workspace/prover_job/prover-testcases/ANT/build.xml:7: taskdef class com.provar.testrunner.ant.CompileTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

```
Build.xml file:

   <project default="runtests">
   <property environment="env"/>
   <property name="provar.home" value="provar-code/ant"/>
   <property name="testproject.home" value="../prover-testcases"/>
   <property name="testproject.results" value="../prover- 
          testcases/ANT/Results"/>

<taskdef name="Provar-Compile" classname="com.provar.testrunner.ant.CompileTask" classpath="${provar.home}/ant-provar.jar"/>
<taskdef name="Run-Test-Case" classname="com.provar.testrunner.ant.RunnerTask" classpath="${provar.home}/ant-provar.jar;${provar.home}/ant-provar-bundled.jar;${provar.home}/ant-provar-sf.jar"/>
<taskdef name="Test-Cycle-Report" classname="com.provar.testrunner.ant.TestCycleReportTask" classpath="${provar.home}/ant-provar.jar;${provar.home}/ant-provar-bundled.jar;${provar.home}/ant-provar-sf.jar"/>

<target name="runtests">

    <Provar-Compile provarHome="${provar.home}" projectPath="${testproject.home}"/>

    <Run-Test-Case provarHome="${provar.home}" 
            projectPath="${testproject.home}" 
            resultsPath="${testproject.results}" 
            resultsPathDisposition="Increment" 
            testEnvironment="" 
            webBrowser="Chrome" 
            webBrowserConfiguration="Full Screen" 
            excludeCallableTestCases="false" 
            salesforceMetadataCache="Reuse" 
            projectCachePath="../../.provarCaches" 
            testOutputlevel="WARNING" 
            pluginOutputlevel="WARNING"
            stopTestRunOnError="false"
            invokeTestRunMonitor="true"
            licensePath="C:\Users\prudhvi.raju.chintam\Provar\.licenses\Provar License.properties"
            >

        <fileset dir="../tests/SalesTEST"><include name="NAMUSER SP4 Opp Business process steps .testcase"/></fileset><fileset dir="../tests/SalesTEST"><include name="sprint4 Opp creation KAMUSER customer Launch Date as Future Date.testcase"/></fileset><fileset dir="../tests/SalesTEST"><include name="sprint4 Opp creation KAMUSER customer Launch Date today.testcase"/></fileset><fileset dir="../tests/SalesTEST"><include name="sprint4 Opp creation KAMUSER with Commite Approved date As future Date.testcase"/></fileset><fileset dir="../tests/SalesTEST"><include name="sprint4 Opp creation KAMUSER with Commite Approved date As Today.testcase"/></fileset><fileset dir="../tests/SalesTEST"><include name="sprint4 Opp creation KAMUSER.testcase"/></fileset><fileset dir="../tests/SalesTEST"><include name="sprint4 Opp creation NAMUSER Commite Approval Date Futuredate.testcase"/></fileset><fileset dir="../tests/SalesTEST"><include name="sprint4 Opp creation NAMUSER Commite Approval Date today.testcase"/></fileset><fileset dir="../tests/SalesTEST"><include name="sprint4 Opp creation NAMUSER customer Launch Date Future date.testcase"/></fileset><fileset dir="../tests/SalesTEST"><include name="sprint4 Opp creation NAMUSER customer Launch Date today.testcase"/></fileset>

    </Run-Test-Case>

</target>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check executing in verbose mode? using ant -v ? Also, is ${provar.home}  resolved correctly?

Comment: I got this error: BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\bandapally.naresh\ADOPE\prover-poc\ANT\build.xml:30: Failed to locate .testproject file.  Expected location: C:\Users\bandapally.naresh\ADOPE\prover-poc\.testproject

Comment: This is again something related to paths and configuration. Check if your ant file configurations, such as variables and their paths matches the paths on your system. All relative paths will be resolved from the basedir. Default basedir is the directory where your build.xml is located.

Comment: Thanks for all your support. I figured it out.

Comment: So what was the issue? Do post about it as answer, so that the topic will be closed and anyone looking for same issue will get an idea on how to resolve it

Comment: I have resolved this issue by giving a proper paths in the build.xml file.